# Dominating Real, Cohen.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm trying to understand if the following claim is true:
Assume that in $M, \mathbb{P}=\mathrm{Fn}(I,2)$ and $|I|> \omega$.
Assume that $G$ is $M$-generic. Let  $f \in \omega^{\omega} \cap M[G]$.

Then there is $X \in M$ countable, 
such that there is an $H ⊆ Fn(X,2)$  $M$-generic s.t. $f \in M[H]$.
This claim, I believe, shows up in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162737/how-to-show-that-the-cohen-forcing-adding-arbitrary-many-reals-adds-no-dominatin).

I'm having a hard time to see why this is true. It`ll be nice if someone could explain this to me or give some hints.
is it an ordinary ccc argument?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here is a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Please use it to improve the formattnig of your question.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: The title has absolutely nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to see this. While not the shortest argument, I believe the generality and elegance of the following proof is well worth the additional time it takes to understand it: (It's essentially taken from [Kunen's book on Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848900503), p. 266ff.)

Let us fix some transitive model $M \models \mathrm{ZFC}$. We work in/over $M$.

*Definition.* Let $\mathbb P$ be a forcing and fix $\tau \in M^{\mathbb P}$. A nice name for a subset of $\tau$ is a name of the form
$$
\bigcup \{  \sigma \times A_{\sigma}\mid \sigma \in \operatorname{dom}(\tau) \},
$$
where each $A_{\sigma} \subseteq \mathbb P$ is an antichain in $\mathbb P$.

*Fact.*(Lemma IV.3.10 of Kunen's book) If $\mathbb P$ is a forcing, $\tau, \mu \in M^{\mathbb P}$, then there is a nice name $\theta \in M^{\mathbb P}$ for a subset of $\tau$ such that
$$
1 \Vdash_{\mathbb P}^{M} \mu \subseteq \tau \implies \mu = \theta.
$$

Now let's return to your situtation and fix a $\mathrm{Fn}(I,2)$-name $\mu$ such that $\mu^G = f$. Since $f \subseteq (\omega \times \omega)$ we may assume, without loss of generality, that 
$$
1 \Vdash_{\mathrm{Fn}(I,2)}^{M} \mu \subseteq \check{(\omega \times \omega)}.
$$

By the fact we may thus fix a nice name $\theta \in M^{\mathrm{Fn}(I,2)}$ for a subset of $\check{(\omega \times \omega)}$ such that
$$
1 \Vdash_{\mathrm{Fn}(I,2)}^{M} \theta = \mu.
$$
For future reference let us write
$$
\theta = \{ \sigma \times A_{\sigma} \mid \sigma \in \operatorname{dom}(\check{(\omega \times \omega)}) \}.
$$
Next note that
$$
\operatorname{dom}{\check{(\omega \times \omega)}} = \{ \check{(m,n)} \mid m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
is countable. Furthermore, since $\mathrm{Fn}(I,2)$ satisfies the ccc, every antichain appearing in the nice name $\theta$ is countable. 
Let 
$$
X := \bigcup \{ \operatorname{dom}(p) \mid \exists \sigma \in \operatorname{dom}(\check{(\omega \times \omega)}) \colon p \in A_{\sigma} \}.
$$

$X$ is countable and $\theta$ is a $\mathrm{Fn}(X,2)$-name as can be easily verified.

The rest is now an easy computation:

*Exercise.* $H := G \cap \mathrm{Fn}(X,2)$ is $\mathrm{Fn}(X,2)$-generic over $M$ and $\theta^H = \theta^G = f \in M[H] \subseteq M[G]$.

For more details and additional hints see Example III.3.64, Definition IV.3.8, Lemma IV.3.10, Lemma IV.4.2 and Lemma IV.4.10 of [Kunen's book on Set Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848900503).

Comment: Thank you sir, this is just what I needed.

Comment: You're very welcome!